# Django: ¿Cómo funciona el sistema de permisos y perfiles de usuarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy comenzando con este framework y he topado con esta gran duda.

Estoy creando una web de búsqueda de empleo (proyecto educativo), donde deben registrase:

- candidatos
- empresas
- usuarios de cada empresa (la empresa es quien registra)

Extendí el modelo `User` de Django:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser
```

Dentro de mi apps.Candidato

```
class user(AbstractUser):
          "'no he aumentado ningun campo extra solo he modificado el campo de autenticacion para que sea el email y no username en campo requerido"'
```

Ahora quiero crear el mismo modelo para `apps.Empresa` y otro para `Userempresa`.

Lo que pretendo es que una empresa y sus usuarios inicien sesión desde el template `Empresa`, y los candidatos inicien en otra template candidato. Mi duda es como un candidato al iniciar sesión no pueda ingresar a la pagina de empresa ni menos la empresa al iniciar sesión pueda ingresar a la pagina de candidatos.. y solo muestre el template del formulario

Perdon si me equivoco en afirmar que en Django no se puede mantener dos sesiones de usuario (candidato, empresa) abiertas a la vez,

Mi  pregunta general es ¿Como debo de crear mis modelos para cada app? ¿como debo usar los permisos? ¿Como debo crear los perfiles?

Comment: Si la diferencia es muy grande en cuanto a datos a ingresar ya sea en el login o en el registro, tendrías que hacer un formulario personalizado para cada modelo correspondiente, con sus respectivas validaciones según lo necesites.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la actualización, tendrías que crear un "login" personalizado para cada modelo por así decirlo, eso implica tener una vista de "login" para cada modelo y las validaciones, etc.

---

> Mi duda es como un `candidato` al iniciar sesión, no pueda ingresar a la pagina de `empresa` ni menos la empresa al iniciar sesión pueda ingresar a la pagina de `candidatos`.. y solo muestre el `template` del formulario

No te entendí muy bien en cuanto al formulario, pero en cuanto a evitar que se registre una persona como `candidato` y después se registre como `empresario` es imposible, a menos que tengas un login a nivel general e identifiques a cada usuario y lo relaciones con un modelo que seria una lista de `cadidatos` y `empresarios`, y hagas las respectivas validaciones, pero eso ya no es viable, y en mi opinión lo considero de mala practica.

Una solución mas favorable seria hacer un login normal como el de Django y tu encargarte de verificar quien va a ser `cadidato` o `empresario`, enviando un email u otra cosa, algo así. Y así te encargas crear las respectivas instancias.

---

> Perdón si me equivoco en afirmar que en Django no se puede mantener
>   dos sesiones de usuario (candidato, empresa) abiertas a la vez.

De seguro se puede pero seria muy complicado, y creo que es un tema avanzado de Django del cual desconozco, supongo que habría que modificar el objeto `request` o algo así, para así identificar los varios usuarios.

---

> ¿Como debo de crear mis modelos para cada `app`? ¿como debo usar los
>   permisos? ¿Como debo crear los perfiles?

1. En cuanto a **¿Como debo de crear mis modelos para cada `app`?** pues dependiendo de los datos que necesites, es logico.
2. En cuanto a **¿Como debo usar los permisos?** pues ¿Que tipo permisos?, ¿Permisos en que sentido?, es una pregunta muy general, especifica mas en tus preguntas.
3. En cuento a **¿Como debo crear los perfiles?**, pues de eso te debes encargar tu pues eres tu el que estas diseñando la `app`, ademas de que no tiene nada que ver con el tema.

Bueno espero haber aclarado tus dudas, Saludos!